# How to get browser history from the last hour

Tags: java, android, browser-history

I want to get all the browser history records from browsers, but only for the last hour.

I tried this code, but it gets all browser history, and i want to get browser history from only the last hour.

```
 Cursor mCur = activity.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        mCur.moveToFirst();
        if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
                Log.v("titleIdx", mCur
                        .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
                Log.v("urlIdx", mCur
                        .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
                mCur.moveToNext();
            }
        }
```

Comment: zombie question.  2.5 years old and edited today?  crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX`.
It will return the date in milliseconds (long), so use:

```
long date;
Cursor mCur = activity.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
            Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    mCur.moveToFirst();
    if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            date=Long.parseLong(mCur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_DATE_INDEX));
            if(date > System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000*3600) {
              Log.v("titleIdx", mCur
                    .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
              Log.v("urlIdx", mCur
                    .getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
             }
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```